# iOS crash CoreData: error: (19) PRIMARY KEY must be unique

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I just integrated core data in an app and when the user launches it for the first time I create the core and start adding informations from an XML, here is the code that I am using:

```
for (int count = 0; count < suggestionsResponseDict.count; count++) {

    NSLog(@"add core data element at position: %d",count);

    SuggestedChannelsEntity *suggestedCellData = (SuggestedChannelsEntity*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SuggestedChannelsEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"Name"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupTags:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"Tags"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupNumberOfMembers:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"Members"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatarThumbnail:@"null"];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatarThumbnailLink:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"AvatarThumnail"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatar:@"null"];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatarLink:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"Avatar"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatar:@"null"];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupIsMember:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"permission"]]];

    NSError *managedObjError = nil;

    if (![context save:&managedObjError]) {
        NSLog(@"Next error ocured:%@ while uploading element:%d", managedObjError, count);
    }
}
```

suggestionsResponseDict is the XML in dictionary format.

My app crashes on the line:

```
if (![context save:&managedObjError])
```

If I don't understand what I am doing wrong, because the same code works if the user register or logs in and the core data is created when he enters the app, but the same code crashes if the user logs in, enters the app and then he request the data manually and core data is created.

Before integrating crashlytics for better logs I was getting these report when the app was crashing:

```
global ID may not be temporary when recording
```

Update I have changed the code in :

```
for (int count = 0; count < suggestionsResponseDict.count; count++) {

    NSLog(@"add core data element at position: %d",count);

    SuggestedChannelsEntity *suggestedCellData = (SuggestedChannelsEntity*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SuggestedChannelsEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"Name"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupTags:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"Tags"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupNumberOfMembers:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"Members"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatarThumbnail:@"null"];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatarThumbnailLink:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"AvatarThumnail"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatar:@"null"];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatarLink:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"Avatar"]]];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupAvatar:@"null"];
    [suggestedCellData setGroupIsMember:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[suggestionsResponseDict objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"permission"]]];

}

    NSError *managedObjError = nil;

    if (![context save:&managedObjError]) {
        NSLog(@"Next error ocured:%@ while uploading element:%d", managedObjError, count);
    }
```

And now it works, I don't know if the problem was that I was saving the context to often but at leas now it works.

Comment: Hi This kind of error comes when you insert mangedobject in context which is already inserted in context..  And note that bug is not in given code , Please save context before for loop starts. the app will crash there.

Comment: @BevinPatel so, you suggest to add: `NSError *managedObjError = nil;

    if (![context save:&managedObjError]) {
        NSLog(@"Next error ocured:%@ while uploading element:%d", managedObjError, count);
    }`  before the code,  just to see if it crash? and how will this help me?

Comment: You can identify that the bug is not in for loop. you are re-inserting the mangedobject in context before fore loop executes,

Comment: Are you using data that has been created or edited outside of the app, for example by using a SQLite editor? For example, some kind of initial pre-loaded content?